# How to make AJAX requests synchronous without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I have a simple AJAX request which loads a .txt file:

```
var game = {
loadWordList : function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET", "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/deekayen/4148741/raw/01c6252ccc5b5fb307c1bb899c95989a8a284616/1-1000.txt", false);

    request.onreadystatechange = function request_word_list(){
        if(request.readyState === 4)
            if(request.status === 200 || request.status == 0){
                this.allWords = request.responseText.split('\n'); // MAIN ISSUE!
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
    }
    request.send(null);
},
```

The main issue is that after I declare the variable `this.allWords` it returns `undefined` after using it somewhere else.

For example, if I type:
`console.log(game.allWords);`

The output will be `undefined` and **not** the list of words.

How can I make JavaScript wait until AJAX completes its request?

Comment: Using [jquery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)  you can use `async: false`. However, using another methods can solve de problem asynchronously.

Comment: I think what you want is to make the AJAX requests synchronous

Comment: set a variable and have a setTimeout check if that variable has been set by the response of the request

Comment: This question hides an underlying misunderstanding on how Ajax is supposed to work. Ajax is, by design, asynchronous, as you should not force the user to wait while a server you potentially do not control returns the value.
In a short sentence... I would suggest you to change the way your application and, and try to use `game.allwords` inside `onreadystatechange` .

Comment: wow, **stop**. Abyss ahead. You do not want to go down that road. Synchronous AJAX requests are deprecated, and that for a good reason. A sync ajax request means freezing **everything** on the page untill the response is there, in the hope that this will be so quick that the user doesn't notice/care. Long story short, check out Promises (or `async/await`), and how to use them. That's the best way to go here.

Comment: +1 on the terrible idea. In addition to what @EricWu and Thomas already mentioned (Promises) another option is callbacks. All depends on what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

What you need are Promises, async/await and the new fetch API.

(async () => {
    const game = {};

```
game.loadWordList = () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let res = await fetch("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/deekayen/4148741/raw/01c6252ccc5b5fb307c1bb899c95989a8a284616/1-1000.txt");
        let text = await res.text();
        resolve(text.split('\n'))
    })
}

try {
    game.allWords = await game.loadWordList();
    console.log(game.allWords);
}
catch(err) {
    throw Error(err); // something went wrong with the request
}
```

})()

A promise is used when you need to get a job done but you don't know how much time it will take or in what order it will occur,
the promise can either be resolved, which means the task ran successfully, or it can be rejected meaning there was an error.

fetch is a promise based API, which is more or less the modern replacement for XMLHttpRequests,

by using the concepts of async/await you can make your code "wait" until a promise has resolved by using the await keyword,

here we are waiting until the fetch has successfully retrieved your data, and then only allowing the rest of the code following it to execute, if any error occurs, the try catch block will handle it.

Here are some resources if you want to look into the above mentioned topics in more detail,

https://javascript.info/promise-basics

https://javascript.info/async-await